# Strange behavious use boost::geometry::within() for polygon and ring

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry, debian-stretch

I develop an application on ***Debian 9*** with the ***boost-1.62.0*** installed by `sudo apt-get install` command. I found an strange behavious when to call `boost::geometry::with_in(polygon, ring)`. The polygon intersect with the ring, but not with in. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/intersection.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/ring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::geometry;

int main()
{
    using Point = boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
    using Polygon = boost::geometry::model::polygon<Point>;
    using Ring = boost::geometry::model::ring<Point>;

    Ring outer;
    append(outer, Point(-6.46720129179205, 15.61591992211971));
    append(outer, Point(-3.617204647384145, 15.61591992211971));
    append(outer, Point(-3.617204647384145, 7.615919922119708));
    append(outer, Point(-6.46720129179205, 7.615919922119708));
    append(outer, Point(-6.46720129179205, 15.61591992211971));

    Polygon polygon;
    polygon.outer() = outer;
    correct(polygon);

    Ring ring;
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 7.615919922119709));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 6.81591992211971));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 6.015919922119708));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 5.215919922119708));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 4.415919922119708));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 3.615919922119708));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 2.815919922119709));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 2.015919922119709));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 1.215919922119709));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 0.4159199221197081));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, -0.3840800778802915));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588097, -0.3840800778802916));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588097, 0.415919922119708));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588097, 1.215919922119709));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588097, 2.015919922119709));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588097, 2.815919922119709));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588097, 3.615919922119708));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588096, 4.41591992211971));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588097, 5.215919922119709));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588097, 6.015919922119709));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588097, 6.815919922119708));
    append(ring, Point(-6.542202969588097, 7.615919922119708));
    append(ring, Point(-3.542202969588097, 7.615919922119709));
    correct(ring);

    cout << boolalpha
         << within(polygon, ring) << endl /* should return false */
         << covered_by(polygon, ring) << endl; /* should retrurn false */

    return 0;
}
```

Build and run:

```
 g++ -g -o wi wi.cpp
 ./wi
```

Get the result:

```
 true
 true
```

The polygon ***is not*** inside ring, but `boost::geometry::within(polygon, ring)` return `true`.

[image: boost_within]

So is it the boost-1.62 bug? And how to fix it.

Comment: Also true for 1.58. Are you sure your calc is correct?

Comment: It's strange. The polygon is not inside the ring.

Comment: For the future, it would help if you provide a picture which will show, what your desired behavoir is. I had to do it with excel now and I can see, that they do not intersect

Comment: Does the same behaviour occur with different (simpler) polygons and point coordinates? It would help greatly with debugging if the problem could be simplified.

Comment: The ring is exactly a rectangle with the point list: `Point(-3.542202969588097, 7.615919922119709), Point(-3.542202969588097, -0.3840800778802915), Point(-6.542202969588097, -0.3840800778802916), Point(-6.542202969588097, 7.615919922119708), Point(-3.542202969588097, 7.615919922119709)` which dose not contains the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

The difference 7.615919922119709 - 7.615919922119708 is 1×10^-15.

This means that the geometries overlap vertically. According to the Simple Feature spec of the standard this means they satisfy `within`:

[Create solid polygon in boost geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312330/create-solid-polygon-in-boost-geometry/47316414#47316414)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! Could you explain more clearly why the satisfy `within` and how can I fix that? Intuitively the polygon is not inside the ring. Thanks.